# Is hidden gmail forwarding plausible?

Tags: account-security, gmail

I'm currently investigating a situation where apparently emails I have sent from my gmail account have been also forwarded to another gmail account, without my being aware of it.

Is this plausible or feasible - that an email can be auto-forwarded, but not appear in "Sent Mail" and for the auto-forward rule to be hidden somehow?

What measures could I take to:

- Establish whether this may have occurred?
- Prevent it from re-occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sent emails can be deleted from the "Sent Mail" easily as part of a script. So that part is feasible.

Forwarding rules are meant for users to change, so there is no function to 'hide' a rule.

More likely that someone is logging into your account. Change your password and use 2FA on your account.

Comment: I eventually found the culprit and got them to confess how they did it.  I left my laptop unattended, briefly, and in the 60 seconds before the screen saver they alt-tabbed into my gmail, sent the email to their own account, and then deleted from the "Sent" folder.